# How to add a group to a project in gitlab by API curl?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have many project in my Gitlab and I want to add a group to all of my project.

I'm looking for a curl command to invite a group to my Gitlab project.

for example maintainer privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/:id/projects/:project_id"
```

Please refer Gitlab docs for more details

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html

Comment: I got error: curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: curl --request POST--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "http://192.X.X.X:8000/api/v4/groups/groups/4/projects/9"

Comment: @MohammadRavanbakhsh, so you are running gitlab in your local network. are you able to hit any other api?

Comment: Yes for example I can get my project ID by api curl. gitlab is in my local network

Comment: could you check command again if u missed any space, as I could see u did not put space after --request POST in you curl command. pls separate POST--header with space

Comment: I manage to add user to a project with REST PUT /api/v4/poject_id/member_id?access_level=30 but with group of members it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to add group of members to a project with max role let's say 30?